# mongodb - lookup comma separated values from another collection and get details

Tags: mongodb

I am able to look up another collection and get the required data when the field I am looking only has one value.

Queries can become too long so I am including a working playground below. It gets the first value but not the second.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q9j7K24Yk7x

In the example above, I want to get category text for "245, 276".

I am doing it like below.  I know that `$arrayElemAt` gets only the first value before the comma but that is what my question is. How to modify it to get multiple values when for example `$category` is a comma separated value(s) like.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "categories",
    as: "category",
    let: {
      category: {
        $toInt: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$category",
                ","
              ]
            },
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Joe has explained perfectly why its happening, You can correct query this way,

- `$addFields` to convert category string to array using `$map`, `$split`, `$toInt` and `$trim`,
- `$lookup` without pipeline
- `$unwind` deconstruct category array
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      category: {
        $map: {
          input: { $split: ["$category", ","] },
          in: { $toInt: { $trim: { input: "$$this" } } }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      as: "category",
      localField: "category",
      foreignField: "_id"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$category",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$category._id",
      categoriesText: "$category.text"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/92Yrc38lj4k)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage to storing the value as array instead of comma separated string in terms of performance?

Comment: yes ofcourse, it affects because look at the first stage $addFields, you have to use extra 4 operators to just convert string to array, and when you have already an array then its good, you can prevent extra operations.

Comment: I see, I will change the code to start storing as array because it might help in searching category in future. Your answer is correct but I think its better if I change my approach to store as array.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a string that contains a list of numbers.  When you `$split` that string and use `$arrayElemAt`, you get only 1 of the values.

- change the schema.
  Instead of storing a string `category: "245, 276"`, store an array `category; [245, 276]`.  This would reduce the work necessary for each query, and make it more easily indexible.
- use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation) to convert all of the values after splitting, and match with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation) operator instead of `$eq`.